# ag-grid-community: how to set a title for the grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I would like to use ag-grid (community edition) with the alpine theme in my react web app.  I'm looking for a way to add a title to my grid, so it will use the same theme.

I expected a "title" property on the grid, but can't find it in the docs.  Is there a way to pass an ag-grid a title for the whole grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, I don't see any sort of Title customization in the ag-grid documentation. Meaning, you have to roll out your own.

One possible solution would be to use the [Theme Customization Functionality](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes-customising/) of ag-grid to add the styling that you're looking for.

Another solution would be just to simply add/style an `<h1>` tag before the grid component

```
<div>
    <h1>Grid Title</h1>
    <AgGridComponent props={/** ... **/} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

we wrap ag-Grid inside AdapTable and that has a Dashboard which includes a title.  Makes it really easy to name each instance of ag-Grid (we have many!)